# Enzyme, Jest, React - two related inputs, one does not change state

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Given this code

```
findSelect(component, 1, 0).simulate('change', a)
findSelect(component, 1, 1).simulate('change', b)

component.find('button[type="submit"]').simulate('click')

expect(onSearch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(someOtherObject, {
  'ONE FIELD': a,
  'SECOND FIELD': b,
})
```

where findSelect finds same component at different index, and someOtherObject is not relevant right now.
the problem is that the 'ONE FIELD' apparently is assigned with empty string instead of right value, when b, which is dependent of value of a (a needs a to be filled first) got the proper value.

**this test was working before upgrading** react from v15 to v16 and enzyme from v2.9 to v3.3 and jest from v21 to v23. as far I was unable to find a similar case, but my shot is that the problem is some change in react/enzyme I don't know about yet

Additional info:

- component is shallow rendered

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using `wrapper.update()` here and there solves the problem. a bit ugly but couldn't find better solution to this